# When is the right moment to bump a package version in a CI/CD pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, npm, continuous-integration, publish

I am creating a Jenkins pipeline to build and publish an npm package. I have a dilemma when to bump the version of the package in package.json. If the version is changed on every push in a feature branch then the developer has the option to manually choose whether it's a major, minor or a patch change. On the negative side, it's possible to make several pushes which will change the version more than once. If, however, the version bump happens after the merge into main then there is no control over the semver and the change must either be pushed in a new commit into main or in a new branch which has to be merged into main again. So my question is whether there is a best practice on how this is done.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be an agreed-upon standard for when versions should change in the development process (this is more a development process question than a Jenkins one).

Quite a few people follow [GitFlow](https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html) which uses multiple branches to "protect" the version.

- Master branch - Always working and releasable
- Develop/integration branch - Target branch for developers to merge feature branches
- Feature branch - Based on develop/integration and is where work occurs

For the pipeline you could then set it to only publish the NPM package when a change to master occurs, I would recommend tagging it with the version as well.

If you are doing testing on the branches I would recommend not publishing a package at all, but let the pipeline checkout the branch and install the package locally.

If you have to publish on every commit I would recommend using `git describe` for the version.

Comment: Any tips on where to find more information of the alternatives? My struggle is the steps to take. I would reason if you bump the version in a release pipeline that pipeline needs to build and test the commit. Then bump the version, commit the new bumped version, build it again, test it again (might be unnecessary) and save in an artifactory. Or would you just build and test in the integration pipeline and just bump version, recommit, build the artifact and upload it in the release pipeline?